# Would like MainActivity to show when Completely loaded

Tags: android, xml

My code counts to 100% with progress bar on SplashActivity and shows MainActivity. But on my MainActivity I still have to wait approximately 10 secs before functionality kicks in.

How to fix this?

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_splash);

        progressBar=(ProgressBar)findViewById(R.id.progressBar);
        progressBar.setProgress(0);
        textView=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.textView);
        textView.setText("");

        final long period = 100;
        timer=new Timer();
        timer.schedule(new TimerTask() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                //this repeats every 100 ms
                if (i<100){
                    runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                        @Override
                        public void run() {
                            textView.setText(String.valueOf(i)+"%");
                        }
                    });
                    progressBar.setProgress(i);
                    i++;
                }else{
                    //closing the timer
                    timer.cancel();
                    Intent intent =new Intent(SplashActivity.this,MainActivity.class);
                    startActivity(intent);
                    // close this activity
                    finish();
                }
            }
        }, 0, period);
    }

}
```

Comment: You start your main activity after your progress bar is completed. The activity takes a while because it is loaded after the splash screen completes. Why is your main activity hanging? Maybe fix the issue on the main activity in stead of trying to mask it with a loader?

Comment: did you work any heavy operation on your main activity?

Comment: For MainActivity i am pointing to "webView.loadUrl" where i am loading html, js and css to present my app. I have a button calling a JAVAscript but that it what seems to be taking 10 secs to work. The rest of the interface loads fine.

Comment: @user1032337 just add the network consuming task in Async thread of your activity. So Ui thread wont get block.

Comment: Thanks for the help every on the problem was in my javascript function  call

Answer (score 0):

Use **ViewTreeObserver**  to get UI loading complete event

```
ViewTreeObserver vto = mylayout.getViewTreeObserver();      
vto.addOnGlobalLayoutListener(new OnGlobalLayoutListener() {          
     @Override          
     public void onGlobalLayout() {              
        // do something now when the object is loaded 

     }      
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Like below and once page loaded completely then dismiss the dialog and show it to the user.

```
private ProgressDialog dialog = new ProgressDialog(MainActivity.this);

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

WebView webView = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.webView1);

Bundle extras = getIntent().getExtras();
String url=extras.getString("adres");

webView.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient() {
    @Override
    public void onPageFinished(WebView view, String url) {                  
        if (dialog.isShowing()) {
            dialog.dismiss();
        }
    }
});
dialog.setMessage("Loading..Please wait.");
dialog.setCanceledOnTouchOutside(false);
dialog.show();
webView.loadUrl(url);



WebSettings webSettings = webView.getSettings();
webSettings.setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
}
```